# How to append HTML form data into a doc/txt file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, excel, forms

I have a form with multiple inputs and drop-downs, I want to store this data (keep appending future data) into a text file. I don't wish to use PHP or any other language.

I need to fetch back this data later probably into excel, so storing it in json would be a possible approach.

Please guide me on how to do this, I am a beginner in javascript, also suggest if any better approach is possible using just javascript (vanilla).

Comment: Hi, the way this site works is that you're expected to show some of the code that you have already tried, so that others can give you concrete answers and recommendations. If you are looking for a tutorial, this is usually not the right place. I recommend taking the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i've built a fully working example using vanilla javascript for you.
In this example there is a form with 3 fields. and a submit button.
When the submit is clicked the function handle submit is invoked.
Than a blob file is created with the desired text.
And it automatically downloads the file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function makeFile(text) {
                var newFile = new Blob(text.split(), { type: 'text/plain' })
                var newFileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(newFile);
                var link = document.getElementById('submit');
                link.href = newFileUrl;
                link.download = true;
            }

            var handleSubmit = () => {
                var field1 = document.getElementById('field1').value
                var field2 = document.getElementById('field2').value
                var field3 = document.getElementById('field3').value

                makeFile(`${field1},${field2},${field3}`);
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1">
            <div>
                <span>field1:</span>
                <input type="text" id='field1' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>field2:</span>
                <input type="text" id='field2' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>field3:</span>
                <input type="text" id='field3' />
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="#" download id="submit" onclick="handleSubmit()">Submit</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also need to append more data in the future, not just keep downloading new file everytime. Is that possible?

Comment: Once a blob object is created it is read only. You can always create a new file and download it again. and also you can remove the download attribute from the <a> tag. and add it manualy in the code. whenever you wish to download the file.